# Passing GUID through C# as parameter to Crystal Reports throws an error

Tags: c#, parameters, crystal-reports, guid

My stored procedure has a GUID as a input parameter and at first it threw an error:

> Type mismatch

That happened because I was passing it like a string. Then I did this:

```
Guid parameterGuid = Guid.Parse(parameterGuid);

MainReport.SetParameterValue(kvp.Key, parameterGuid,MainReport.Subreports["HeaderSubreport"].Name);
```

And after that I got this error message:

> Value does not fall within the expected range

So, after the search I took I saw that it needs to be passed as an array, but I am not sure how to do that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I recall correctly, Crystal Reports require the GUID to be enclosed with curly braces. So it looks like:

```
{xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}
```

You could do some string concatenation to achieve this. Or from `Guid` you can use `ToString("B")`.